# Using request module in python for writing in my Influx DataBase via the HTTP API

Tags: python, api, curl, influxdb

I tried to convert this cUrl command who actually work, in python :

`curl -i -XPOST 'http://51.255.80.74:8086/write?db=testdb' --data-binary 'cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.65'`

By doing this, i'm adding a time-serie data in my influx database testdb via the HTTP API.
I want to do the same in my python script using the request module, but i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "script3.py", line 27, in <module>
    response = requests.post(urlPostData, data=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 94, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

My script python is :

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

###
interestingData = ['lps0','wuc0']

###INFLUXDB INFOS
databaseName = 'testdb'
urlPostData = 'http://51.255.80.74:8086/write?db='+databaseName

urlGetData = 'http://192.168.168.110/admin/status.xml'
source = requests.get(urlGetData, stream=True)

tree = ET.parse(source.raw)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
        if child.tag in interestingData:
                data = ''+child.tag+',host=serverlama,region=us-west value='+child.text
                response = requests.post(urlPostData, data=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, i think i converted well my cURl in python request.

Comment: What is the traceback ?

Comment: I have edit my post with the complete error message. Yes, i'm trying to post in my database using python request module, and it doesn't work, but it work when i do a cUrl. My backend is already configured.